# CMAKE & ESP IDF: how to include components as subfolders?

Tags: cmake, esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf

My project looks like this,

```
.components
...drivers
......usb
........usb.c
........usb.h
......lcd
......etc
.main
...main.c
```

In main.c, I would like to include libraries as

```
#include "drivers/usb.h"
#include "drivers/lcd.h"
```

How to configure CMake to include subfolders, but include component itself as a folder?

I have tried to include subfolders as PRIV_INCLUDE_DIRS,
but it works like this,

```
#include "usb/usb.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "component/sourcefile.h"
```

> esp-idf components like driver and FreeRTOS manage to achive this so
> well, just can't figure out how to implement such style.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use a header file outside the component itself, you need to use `INCLUDE_DIRS` instead of `PRIV_INCLUDE_DIRS` when calling `idf_component_register(...)` in the component's `CMakeLists.txt`. For more information, see the [IDF Build System component commands documentation page](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#idf-component-commands).

To enable including header files as `driver/xxx.h`, you can do the following: Add a sub-folder `driver` in each of `usb`, `lcd`, etc., move the respective header files there and add each of the directories (`usb`, `lcd`, etc.), using `INCLUDE_DIRS` in `idf_component_register(...)`.
Your file tree would look like:

```
.components
...drivers
......usb
........usb.c
........driver
..........usb.h
......lcd
........driver
..........lcd.h (not present above, but requested in your code example)
......etc
.main
...main.c
```

This is in fact done for many driver headers in ESP-IDF itself.